# ASP.NET 4.8 - How to make class run in its own instance?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, class, instance

I have a class that multiple users interact with every single minute. Sometimes these users are outside of USA and so they get back results that are different then for users in USA. When I refresh my page while in USA, I see that some of my results are meant for another country. I read that C# class for ASP.NET runs as one for all users at the same time. Meaning that everyone shares the same class. Is there a way to run an instance of the class for each user individually?

Example: Class's variables changed because of a German user and then when I refresh the page my results are German.

I would love to keep my class as is. Its a big class with a lot of data. If there is some way to keep the class in an instance and recreate the class for each user. Please help me out on this. Thank you.

Comment: Classes and session data are orthagonal concepts, can you show how your classes are instanciated, and whether they have static fields, it may help us understand where your problem lies.

Comment: only static properties are shared between requests of the same controller class

Comment: Are you using globalization resources for various locales, and if so how are you switching out resources?

Comment: Yes Iam using a lot of static classes. Is this the reason for such an issue?

Comment: Part 1: Im using static classes which by the way are all set in one main class. I dont use session. To store some cookies I use regular javascript. But this issue could not be from js since Im not loading any server logic into js. In the link below you can see that a drop downlist is being populated from server side. But for some reason only the first element is correct. In this image the first element is in Russian text. The next elements are in Japanese. If I refresh the page then it all becomes Russian since the link Im on is for russian speakers. Japanese should not be loaded for this page

Comment: Part 2: This happens randomly. These drop down elements get there data from my main class. What would cause an issue like this? My original assumption was that when the page loaded some Japanese user was also accessing the class at the same time and override the language static class to be Japanese and this the first element was in Russian but on the override it became Japanese. Is this even possible?
https://servervideos.hopto.org/images/1.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this could be a issue. Each user that logs on to that site and your code creates an instance of that class will not have any relationship or anything else to do with any other users. Now of course a static class? Well, it don't change, and thus once again that could never be of any use for any one user logged on to that system.

So I fail to see how a instance of a class created for each user going to stumble, and step on top of other users - that's really not at all possible, and should not be occurring. Of course to persist such a class, you would have to use session(), or on a per page basis, you could use viewstate.

As noted, it possible you using a static class - but then any and all values in that class will apply to all users logged into the site - such static classes are not per user, but global to the whole web site - and for all and any users.

so you might want to expand on how you are persisting that class on a per user basis?

If you are using session() ? Well, if your hosting is based on a server farm, then since different servers can be used (for load balancing and scalability), then of course you can't use session() "in memory", since each server can't then shuffle and pass that session() to the other server. In these cases, then you have to turn on SQL server based session() management. Once done, then this issue goes away, since it now not server "in memory" that persists this data, but sql server does the dirty work for you. This can somewhat slow down the site - but I find this approach quite much means session() becomes dead 100% reliable, and even code errors and things that cause the app-pool to restart don't blow out session() values. In fact on a lot of servers I used, I had truckloads of session() problems. Turning on sql sessions() and not having to change one line of code? The session() then became 100% dead on 100% reliable and never failed me. Even web site re-starts - and a user sitting on a page seems to still work.

So, how are you persisting that new class instance that you create for each user? Their is no logical reason that I can think of that one session() class instance is going to have any relationship to any other logged on user. So, you might want to expand on how you are and been persisting that class instance that supposed to be "per user"

Comment: Please anyone if you can give me some hints that would be apprecieated. Here is a screenshot of the error I get. 
https://servervideos.hopto.org/images/1.jpg
It loads Russian in a dropdown but then it randomly loaded Japanese for the rest of the items. They should all be in Russian. If I refresh then it becomes all in Russian. This happens randomly and for different languages. Next time it could be English or Italian and so on. All of my language text is stored in one main class.